# my container div doesnt expand vertically on one of my pages as I add elements

Tags: css

My container div doesnt expand vertically on one of my pages as I add elements. Hence the bottom most div overlaps onto my footer. The divs in the container are horizontal elements relatively positioned

On my home page it works fine container expands and no overlapping using the css below

If I had any hair left it would be pulled out by now!! :-))

```
#container {
    width: 900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:50px;
    position:relative;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can't understand `min-height: 100%;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me to little context, because it is possible that the footer is overlapping your container div, which is set to start with a min-height of 100%, it depends on how the footer is defined related to your container div.

Comment: I would like to know how I can comment instead of answering.. : ) (this is a test)

Comment: You need 50 rep to comment on other people's posts - http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Comment: @Brian maybe you have to try without the css property 'top', it is possible that it is those 50 pixels that comes above your footer, but as I said, for me there is to little context, maybe you can add your case at tinkerbin.com like Rohit did..

Comment: Thanks for the help!! :-)) The footer is 100% width outside the container div. Tried to take those 50 pixels away but didnt work.

Comment: @lijn thanks for youe help with this. Tried deleting the 50 pixels but didnt work.

The footer is 100% width and outside the container div.

Comment: @BrianByrne can you give us the whole page source? here or maybe at http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://tinkerbin.com/

Comment: @BrianByrne thx, I 've take a big look : ) the problem is that you don't take the benefit of 'position:static' this is a default property of an htlm-element. I've replace at the big containers the css property 'top' by 'margin-top' and remove 'position:relative' at those elements, except at #sectors and the boxes in this one. the overlapping is gone : ) http://tinkerbin.com/uGWuIcga
if you would like to learn html, etc, I advise you to read a manual, e.g. http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/, this is easy to read and at the same site you can read more.. if any question, just ask..

Comment: @lijn Wow! Thank you so much!! Its great when you know what youre doing!! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

...............***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/xYZK45dI)***

Hi now **give** to `body, html height:100%;` than give to any **class** or **id** `height 100%;`

as like this

```
body, html{
height:100%;
}
```

***[LIve demo](http://tinkerbin.com/xYZK45dI)***

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Already had this in my css. Tried adding 100% height to my id and it actually overlapped worse.

Answer (score 0):

```
rule-selector
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

If this doesn't work for you then a more particular rule might disable this rule, so make your rule-selector as particular as possible. If it is still not particular enough, then:

```
rule-selector
{
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for a lot for this. Im pretty new to this. But that didnt work either im afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#container {
width: 900px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
top:50px;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden ;
}
```

Best,

Cynthia

Comment: actually it didnt work at all. It just chopped off the end of my div!